# Как можно взять определённые значения курсов некоторых валют к рублю с помощью библиотеки Volley?

Tags: java, json, android-volley

Я новичок в программировании, недавно решил сделать простейшее Android приложение, которое показывает курс некоторых валют. Для достижения цели мне посоветовали использовать библиотеку Volley, по этому адресу https://currate.ru/api/?get=rates&pairs=USDRUB,EURRUB&key=8b8fdac67b06df54ed03037bc67e71e4, взять пробное  значение получилось, вот скрины кода [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Но я не могу понять, как брать значения вот с этого источника https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь и прошу прощения, если что-то сделал не так/ нарушил что либо, я тут впервые.

Comment: То, что вы представили по ссылке - является примером Json-файла, который нужно десериализовать в объект. Итак, что вам нужно сделать - создать объект, в котором будут описаны свойства (Date, PreviousDate, PreviousURL, Timestamp, Valute (объект Valute включает в себя следующие свойства: AUD, AZN, GBP,..., которые включают в себя: ID, NumCode, CharCode, Nominal, Name, Value, Previous. Советую создать базовый класс и от него наследоваться)). Далее, обращаетесь к данной url и считываете оттуда все данные и десериализуете их. Далее, делаете с полученным объектом то, что считаете нужным.

Comment: Если будет слишком сложно создать/описать класс, можете воспользоваться каким-нибудь онлайн конвертером, но помните, что они не всегда корректно переводят. Скорее, они являются просто некой подсказкой, как это может выглядеть, но не более того freecodegenerators.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo

Comment: А такую операцию обязательно делать, если нужно получить отношение к рублю всего лишь у четырёх валют(USD,EUR,GBP,CHF)?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Вам это всё нужно сделать. Единственное, если вам какие-то свойства не нужны из json-файла, то не описывайте их в объекте. Допустим, вы хотите создать только лишь 4 валюты. Значит в классе Valute указывайте только свойства с такими названиями

Comment: Я как раз и хотел это узнать, просто не мог правильно сформулировать мысль. Как я понял мне нужно создать объект и описать  свойства, но в объекте Valute я могу указать свойства, которыми я буду пользоваться, а не все сразу, я нигде не ошибся?

Comment: Я ниже привёл пример, как это можно сделать. Добавьте только get и set. Про то, как получить данные из ссылки - https://www.delftstack.com/howto/java/java-get-json-from-url/. Про то, как конвертировать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210070/converting-jsonobject-to-java-object

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, особенно за информационные ресурсы и пример. Вы меня очень сильно выручили!)

Comment: Если ответ помог, поставьте галочку возле него

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот пример, как это может выглядеть. Осталось десериализовать полученные с url данные в этот объект (Information) и делать с ним то, что вам нужно

```
public class Information{
    @JsonProperty("Date") 
    public Date Date;
    @JsonProperty("PreviousDate") 
    public Date PreviousDate;
    @JsonProperty("PreviousURL") 
    public String PreviousURL;
    @JsonProperty("Timestamp") 
    public Date Timestamp;
    @JsonProperty("Valute") 
    public Valute Valute;
}

public class Valute{
    @JsonProperty("USD") 
    public Currency USD;
    @JsonProperty("EUR") 
    public Currency EUR;
    @JsonProperty("GBP") 
    public Currency GBP;
    @JsonProperty("CHF") 
    public Currency CHF;
}

public class Currency{
    @JsonProperty("ID") 
    public String ID;
    @JsonProperty("NumCode") 
    public String NumCode;
    @JsonProperty("CharCode") 
    public String CharCode;
    @JsonProperty("Nominal") 
    public int Nominal;
    @JsonProperty("Name") 
    public String Name;
    @JsonProperty("Value") 
    public double Value;
    @JsonProperty("Previous") 
    public double Previous;
}
```